# Where do splash screens in flutter appear?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/splash-screen/android-splash-screen

On this page, there are three types of splash themes mentioned 
A. Launch theme
B. Normal theme
C. Flutter splash theme

Now i have read through it and tried implementing all of these, but can someone experienced enough tell me where all these three screens appear during the app launch?

P. S. :- There is a fourth type of splash screen that youtubers tutorial about, that splash screen appears as a first widget drawn by flutter so it's not really a splash screen. It's a first widget to be drawn.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Splash screens are typically used by particularly large applications to notify the user that the program is in the process of loading. Nowadays, in mobile apps splash screen is common. Flutter docs mention a native way to implement a splash screen. This splash screen is white by default. You can see a white screen on the launch of the app.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/splash-screen/android-splash-screen
This document mentions steps to edit this white screen.

**A - Launch Theme**
The launch theme is displayed when the app is initializing. This is the very first thing seen on launching the app, even before our homepage is loaded.

**B - Normal Theme**
Provide the default theme for C-Flutter Splash Screen

**C - Flutter Splash Screen**
Each Flutter experience in an app requires a few moments to initialize the Dart isolate that runs the code. This means a user momentarily sees a blank screen until Flutter renders its first frame. This can be seen for a very brief moment after the splash screen disappears and also in some other situations mentioned in docs.

**D- First widget as Splash Screen**
I think this is not the proper way to implement a splash screen as per Flutter docs. But by displaying a widget as a splash screen it offers all the flexibility of flutter to design a custom splash screen, especially for beginners.

If you need to see the changes, follow the docs with implementing each splash screen with different colors or designs, so that you can identify the changes quickly.

Comment: Really like this answer as it differentiates between the various ideas people have for splash screen.

Comment: @abhijith is there any was we can debug or see the Flutter Splash screen(C) as you mentioned it appears for very short time but just wondering how we can see it.

Comment: @RishabhAgrawal I am not sure about this right now. What I am saying in this comment is from the vague memory. If you provide a Normal Theme(B) it is used as the default Flutter Splash Screen.  When I gave like that I see it sometimes when I switch screens. If there is a logo or something we can easily notice this. NB: I haven't gone through the docs now.  What I have said right now is my experience 1 year before. The flutter and its packages have gone through a great change by this time

Comment: thanks for reply, at the end i was able the see normal theme by removing the meta-data(...SplashScreenDrawable) from AndroidManifest.xml